# How to correctly use `gsutil -q stat` in scripts?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am creating a KSH script to check whether a subdirectory is exist on GCS bucket. I am writing the script like this:

```
#!/bin/ksh

set -e
set -o pipefail

gsutil -q stat ${DESTINATION_PATH}/
PATH_EXIST=$?
if [ ${PATH_EXIST} -eq 0 ] ; then
   # do something
fi
```

Weird thing happens when the `${DESTINATION_PATH}/` does not exist, the script exit without evaluating `PATH_EXIST=$?`. If `${DESTINATION_PATH}/` is exist, the script will run normally as expected.

Why does that thing happen? How can I do better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement `set -e` implies that your script will be exited if a command exits with a `non-zero status`.

The [gsutil stat command](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/stat) can be used to check wheter an object exists:

`gsutil -q stat gs://some-bucket/some-object`

It has an exit status of `0` for an existing object and `1` for a non-existent object.

However it is advised against to use it with subdirectories:

> **Note:** Unlike the `gsutil ls` command, the `stat` command does not support
>   operations on sub-directories. For example, if you run the command:
>
> `gsutil -q stat gs://some-bucket/some-subdir/`
>
> gsutil will look for
>   information about an object called `some-subdir/` (with a trailing
>   slash) inside the bucket `some-bucket`, as opposed to operating on
>   objects nested under `gs://some-bucket/some-subdir/`. Unless you
>   actually have an object with that name, the operation will fail.

The reason because your command is not failing when your `${DESTINATION_PATH}/` exists is because if you [create the folder using the Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console#_creatingfolders) i.e the UI, then a placeholder object will be created with its name. But let me be clear, [folders don't exist in Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork), they are just a visualization of the bucket objects hierarchy.

So if you upload an object named `newFolder/object` to your bucket and the `newFolder` does not exists, it will be "created" but your `gsutil -q stat ${DESTINATION_PATH}/` will return exit code `1`. However if you create the folder using the UI and run the same command it will return exit `0`. Thus follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/stat), and avoid using it for checking if a directory exists.

Instead if you want to check whether a subdirectory exists just check if it contains any object inside:

`gsutil -q stat ${DESTINATION_PATH}/*`

Which will return `0` if any object is in the subdirectory and `1` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a short version of this like this

```
if gsutil -q stat "gs://some-bucket/some-object"
then  
    echo "exists"
else
    echo "does not exist"
fi
```